# Django - prevent duplicate POST requests when user clicking submit button multiple times?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

What is most effective way to prevent multiple POST requests from happening if the user is clicking on the "Send Message" button multiple times.

```
<!-- message.html -->
    <form action="{% url 'send_message' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="messagename" name="messagename" maxlength="50" required>
        <textarea id="messagecopy" name="messagecopy" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message">
    </form>
```

**And my views.py**

```
def send_message(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            campaign = Campaign()
            campaign.name = request.POST["messagename"]
            campaign_message = request.POST["messagecopy"]
            campaign.messagecopy = campaign_message
            campaign.save()
            send_message(campaign_message)
            redirect('home')
```

**Update**
I added to my html the following script:

```
function disable_on_click() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
    }
    
  }
```

I updated `<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message">` to `<input type="submit" onclick="disable_on_click()" class="btn" value="Send Message">`

**Now button gets disabled on click but POST request doesn't go through at all**

**Update #2**

Something that worked for me was adding an onsubmit `<form action="{% url 'send_message' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">` and adding myButton as name of button `<input name="myButton" type="submit" class="btn" value="Send Message">`

Answer (score 3):

What you're probably looking for is called idempotency and it can be solved by generating a key that will be part of the POST request and the created database object and is required to be unique.

ok, the issue of multiple POST requests is not solved with this method but at least the critical action of creating multiple entries in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to stop them with js:

script.js (pure js):

```
function disable_on_click() {
  var element = document.getElementById('the-button-id');
  element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

script.js (jquery):

```
$('#the-button-id').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you show your answer with pure javascript / without jquery. what other alternatives are there to handling with js, ex. how could this be handled in the view.py

Comment: Added a pure js function. Short answer is that js will likely be much easier than any python solution in your views.py. Long answer is that you probably can come up with a series of logic to prevent multiple POST submission strictly in your views.py though some initial ideas that come to mind all seem to have more holes than the js solution. There may indeed be a built-by-django solution out there for this issue though I have yet to come across any in my experience.

Comment: Based on your recommendation I made a modification to my code, but it is creating a separate issue, of POST request not going through at all. I've updated my question, can you please take a look.

Comment: I found a potential solution now, not sure of drawbacks